# Create all possible combinations from 2 vectors

Tags: r, vba, combinatorics

I have a txt file with a list of neighbors structured like this:

```
UG   Neigh
6    7
6    504
6    508
6    514
9    11
9    14
10   352

...  ...
```

And I need to create a list of all possible combinations of Neigh for each UG.
Example:

```
6-7
6-504
6-508
6-514
6-7-504
6-7-508
6-7-514
6-504-508
6-504-514
6-508-514
6-7-504-508
9-11
9-14
9-11-14
...
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `expand.grid`

```
do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(df1), sep="-"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try it

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `CJ` function from `data.table` package-

```
library(data.table)
dt <- CJ(UG = dt$UG, Neigh = dt$Neigh, unique = TRUE)
setDT(dt)[, final:=paste0(UG,"-",Neigh)]
```

**Sample data-**

```
dt <- read.table(text="UG   Neigh
6    7
6    504
6    508
6    514
9    11
9    14
10   352",header=T)
```

**Output**-

```
    UG Neigh  final
 1:  6     7    6-7
 2:  6    11   6-11
 3:  6    14   6-14
 4:  6   352  6-352
 5:  6   504  6-504
 6:  6   508  6-508
 7:  6   514  6-514
 8:  9     7    9-7
 9:  9    11   9-11
10:  9    14   9-14
11:  9   352  9-352
12:  9   504  9-504
13:  9   508  9-508
14:  9   514  9-514
15: 10     7   10-7
16: 10    11  10-11
17: 10    14  10-14
18: 10   352 10-352
19: 10   504 10-504
20: 10   508 10-508
21: 10   514 10-514
```

**Note**- You can also specify for unique combinations by using `unique` parameter.

You can also use `crossing` from `tidyr` package

```
> do.call(paste,crossing(dt$UG, dt$Neigh, sep="-"))
```